# How can not writing an extra property for polymorphism TypeInfo in the output JSON by using another property with Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, jackson

For serialize/deserialize JSON using Jackson ObjectMapper, we can add some config to the ObjectMapper so that the ouput json will have an extra type property like "@class".

```
{"@class":"43","value":43,"id":0}
```

The above is a sample of the output JSON, **is it possible to config ObjectMapper not to write an extra property "@class" during serialize and when deserialize, it will depends on the "value" property to identify the polymorphism class**?

Thanks.
Eric